# Android widget only showing up for debug; app icon always showing

Tags: android, widget, installation, signing

My simple widget application installs and works perfectly when signed as a debug app, but as soon as I try to sign it ready for the market, I experience strange behaviour: it doesn't show up in the widget list *until I uninstall the app* when it appears as the standard Android 'I don't have this' robot icon.

Attempting to drag this 'missing' widget to a screen results in a Launcher crash.

To investigate this, I added a MAIN/LAUNCH intent to one of the Activities, and that shows up as expected on install and vanishes when I uninstall.

What's super-creepy is that if I re-install, while the Launcher is displaying the 'I don't have this' robot icon, my widget briefly replaces that icon, and then vanishes from the list.

I don't see any error messages or issued intents in the log, beyond the normal 'I'm un/installing this'.

Is there something stupid and obvious I'm missing, like a 'signed apps must register their widgets specially', that isn't necessary under debug mode?

Here're my manifest and widget properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      package="uk.org.baverstock.appghoul">
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="4"
        android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name="uk.org.baverstock.appghoul.AppGhoulWidgetProvider">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                   android:resource="@xml/appwidget_provider"/>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".Configure"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <!-- Why does this show up, when the widget doesn't? -->
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ControlsChoiceActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            />

    <activity android:name=".ReconfigureWidget"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            />

    <receiver
            android:name=".WidgetRescanner"
            android:label="WidgetRescanner"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>

</application>
</manifest>
```

and the widget properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="72dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:configure="uk.org.baverstock.appghoul.Configure"
android:previewImage="@drawable/icon"
android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
<!--
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/example_keyguard"

 -->
</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought it might relate to some problem with the release signing key being too long, but various experiments show this happens even with a 2048 key.

It also happens when I use Gradle to build http://javatechig.com/android/app-widgets-example-in-android/ so it doesn't seem to be my code.

I can't think anything I do should be able to crash the launcher *after my app is uninstalled*, so it seems to me this has to be an Android bug: I've reported it at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61387